# Path planning in simulator without sensor data

Tags: ros, collision-map, collada, motionplanning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to do path planning in ROS (only during simulation) without using any sensor data (eg. kinect, laser or stereo)?

Since the environment data is stored in collada format through which we have a perfect knowledge of the environment (even location which are not visible to PR2) and this data can be used for checking collision. I think this is how OpenRave also checks for collision while planning and it bypasses the sensor.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57480/path-planning-in-simulator-without-sensor-data/) by [Ashesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4149/ashesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think moveit! can do exactly what you ask for
[You can find it here](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/index.php/MoveIt!)

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2015-05-28**:
That link is not available right now. Would you please update it. I have the same problem.